# Closing all processes holding a given port from shell

Tags: bash

I am trying to automate one of the jobs I am facing again and again.
There are some ports which are sometimes not closed correctly by some previous jobs..

Lets say port 5000,5001

WHat I want to do is see if these ports are open

and kill these ports if they are open

So right now, I am doing

```
lsof -i :5000
```

and

```
 kill -9 pid1
    kill -9 pid2
```

and so on..

Is there a way to pass 5000 and 5001 as arguments and automate this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automate it as you use it do something like this.

Create a bash script, for example call it 'killMyPorts' and add the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 `lsof -i :"${1}" | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $2}}'`
```

Once you made the script executable (chmod u+x), you can execute it as follows:

```
./killMyPorts 5000
```

Comment: `killMyPorts.sh`? Does your system have `ls.elf` too? See http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful

Comment: No it doesn't :-) I removed the extension

Answer (score 1):

`fuser` can do this job for you.

```
kill_port_users() {
  for port; do
    fuser -n tcp -k "$port"
  done
}

kill_port_users 5000 5001
```

Comment: or: echo 5000 5001 | xargs -n 1 fuser -n tcp -k

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
kill -9 `lsof -i :5000`
```

or

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i :5000)
```

Comment: Please don't promote unnecessary use of SIGKILL -- it's a good way to get SHM segments not cleaned up, temporary files unclosed, unwritten data and logs unflushed, etc. and should be used only if absolutely necessary.